# Looping through an array a certain number of times with output going to a textbox

Tags: c#

Each time I buttonclick my button, I would like my loop to execute and each time a single, random day of the week appears in my textBox1. For example, buttonclick-Tuesday, buttonclick-Thursday, buttonclick-Monday, buttonclick-Friday. I need the loop to execute a total of four (4) times. Then close the form.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
  String[] strpleaseloop =    { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
  Random r = new Random();
  int iSelect = r.Next(0, 6);
  textBox1.Text = strpleaseloop[iSelect];
  this.Close();
}
```

Comment: By updating in a row, you will only see the last value ...

Comment: Ok. What's the question here? What issue you are facing with this code ?

Comment: If you want to click between each day then why do you need a loop?

Comment: David, I know I don't need the loop to get the random value each time, I just need a loop to get 4 independent results - 1 per buttonclick. Once I've seen 4 results, I need the form to close.

Comment: Guilherme, it worked. Thanks. Now I can sleep.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should not use a loop. Instead, use a counter. This should work fine.

Outside the button click:

```
int count = 0;
```

Inside the button click:

```
if (count == 4) this.Close();
count++;
String[] strpleaseloop =    { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
Random r = new Random();
int iSelect = r.Next(0, 6);
textBox1.Text = strpleaseloop[iSelect];
```

Also, I strongly recommend you to put the `Random r = new Random();` outside of the button click, because recreating the `Random` class can cause problems in some specific situations. Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673876/multiple-random-numbers-are-the-same).

Comment: Guilherme, thanks but every time I click my button I cannot get the program to stop at 4. I'm new to programming. What do you mean when you say "Outside the button click".